# VBA Crashing On End Statement or Reset When Array Assigned to Range Within Sub

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I am having an issue with VBA crashing whenever the code is prematurely ended via either an End Statement or the Reset button while debugging. This only occurs when an array is assigned to range within a sub routine called from the main sub.

```
Sub TestSub()
    Dim array1() as variant  
    Call GetArray(array1)
    End
End Sub
```

The code will crash is the End Statement is located in either the Main Sub or the called Sub.

```
Private Sub GetArray(ByRef array1)
    array1 = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2))
End Sub
```

Why does this happen, and is there a solution without assigning the array with the main sub.

Comment: Tried your code.  I get the same result.  Maybe something about returning the array to memory?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get an array from a range, use a **UDF:**

```
Public Function GetArray() As Variant
    GetArray = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2))
End Function

Sub main()
    Dim arry
    arr = GetArray()
    MsgBox LBound(arr, 1) & vbCrLf & UBound(arr, 1) & LBound(arr, 2) & vbCrLf & UBound(arr, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: +1. Was just about to post the same idea, but still leaves open the question of *why* this behavior is closing the Application. The dox on `End` statement don't suggest this behavior: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251671(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: @DavidZemens Putting the **End** statement in the *function* will case both the *function* and the *sub* to exit immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If you put either of these statements it will not crash

```
Private Sub GetArray(ByRef array1())
Private Sub GetArray(ByRef array1() as variant)
```

---

NOTE: If you type this in the development VBA....

```
a(,n) as string
```

...the syntax error will crash VBA Excel and Outlook. I did not try the other Office apps.

Just type it on a empty module and it will crash the VBA app.

Apparently the parser cannot work with that syntax combination.

If you type the syntax for a multidimensional array AND

1. have the least significant dimension entered AND
2. have any of the more significant dimensions empty

THEN
The app will crash

EG -- all of these will crash immediately

```
a(,1) as string  
a(,,,1) as string  
a(1,1,,1) as string
```

BUT THESE WILL NOT

```
a(,) as string  
a(,,1,) as string  
a(1,1,,) as string
```